# static import for constants in same file

Tags: java, static-import

To reference a class constant in an annotation present on the same class, the reference must be prefixed with the class name:

```java
package example;

@MyAnnotation(someAttribute = SomeClass.someConstant)
public class SomeClass {

    public static final someConstant = "...";

}
```

Since this can get quite bulky when using multiple constants / string concatenations, I might simply use the following import directive in the same file to eliminate the need for these prefixes:

```java
package example;

import static example.SomeClass.*;

@MyAnnotation(someAttribute = someConstant + more + constants)
public class SomeClass {

    public static final someConstant = "...";
    public static final more = "...";
    public static final constants = "...";

}
```

Is there anything against this, or when could this lead to problems / ambiguities?

*Java Language Specification Chapter 7.5.4 Static-Import-on-Demand Declarations*:
[v8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4), [v11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4), [v17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything against this

No, it's fine.

> when could this lead to problems / ambiguities?

when you get really wild with defining symbols in the file whose names clash with the imports.

For example:

```
package example;

import static example.SomeClass.*;

class SomeClass {
  static int foo;

  void bar() {
    foo = 1;

    String foo = "";
    
    System.out.println(foo);  // Prints the local variable.
  }
}
```

but you should be giving yourself a stern talking to if you're writing code like this, so it's not really an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite convinced yet, since your example only illustrates normal variable shadowing as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JensPiegsa then perhaps the conclusion is "there is no worse ambiguity than from variable shadowing"? :) It's ambiguity for the reader only, the rules for the meaning of a name are unambiguous to the compiler.

Comment: Since the consequence involves refactoring multiple classes, I wanted to be careful. An internet search had not revealed anything useful about this.